# Do I lose any functionality using Visual Studio for Unity 3d?

Tags: unity, visual-studio, monodevelop

MonoDevelop has always had a strange tendency to stop functioning in basic ways ... autocompletion, copy/paste-clipboard, error detecting, and other silly things.

I routinely fix this by running clean / rebuild all, then restarting MonoDevelop. But this is time-consuming. I've read that Monodevelop has issues...

If I switch to Visual Studio will I lose anything at all that I rely on with Monodevelop's integration to unity? Or will I in fact gain?

Comment: I tried both and found advantages and disadvantages in both. But neither has any egregious defects which will prevent you from finishing your project. I would recommend you to try both and form your own opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio is becoming the most fitted IDE in order to develop with Unity. You won't loose anything in comparison to MonoDevelop.

You will still have autocompletion, debugging tools, documentation access, MonoBehavior scripting wizard, ... I have been using Visual Studio along with Unity for years now. I  can't stand Monodevelop anymore.

Check these links :

- https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/unity-tools/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/visual-studio-tools-for-unity